# brace in a string read from file, no expansion

Tags: bash

My case is I have a file named as 'file.txt' which is a list for a bunch of files, just like below:

```
/path/{a,b,c}/file.d
/path/file.e
/path/file.f
```

then I write a bash file contains a loop read from this file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do ls -alh $line;done < file.txt
```

and I found it doesn't work like I want, brace expansion don't work in this situation, so I want to know is there a work around or something in bash?

Comment: Brace expansion does not happen even when quoted: try the following command and watch the output: `echo /path/{a,b,c} /path/"{a,b,c}"`

Comment: Is that brace meant for either a or b or c or its your directory with braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this special case, I would not use brace expansions at all. It's not the correct tool for the job anyways. And the only workaround to make it work is to use `eval` in a dangerous way—not only because of potential malicious users, but just because there might naturally be special characters in a file name that will be misinterpreted by doing so.

The right tool for the job is to use [shell globs with pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).

Here's something to put you on the right track:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ls -alh -- $line
done < file.txt
```

with your file `file.txt` written as:

```
/path/@(a|b|c)/file.d
/path/file.e
/path/file.f
```

You'll be able to use fancy stuff like `*`, `?`, character classes, `+(...)`, `!(...)` *in a safe way*.

Answer (score 3):

Bash first expands braces and then variables. Here is a simpler example:

```
$ a="/path/{a,b,c}"
$ echo $a
/path/{a,b,c}
$ eval 'echo $a'
/path/{a,b,c}
$ eval "echo $a"
/path/a /path/b /path/c
```

You need to enforce a second evaluation with eval.

But double check the input when using eval. You would not like someone to write something like "dummy;dobadthings" in a line of your file...